# getting HC-SR04 ultrasonic sensor data from stm32f411 with rust HAL yields constant value independent of sensor condition

Tags: rust, sensors, hal, stm32f4

So I want to get the distance in cm from my sensor, I already did it with Arduino C and an Arduino compatible board. Now I want to do this with stm32, below is my code (leaving out the conversion of pulse length to sound, as the delta time is constant already at this point.

```rust
#![deny(unsafe_code)]
#![allow(clippy::empty_loop)]
#![no_main]
#![no_std]


use panic_halt as _; // panic handler

use cortex_m_rt::{entry, interrupt};
use stm32f4xx_hal as hal;

use crate::hal::{pac, prelude::*};
use stm32f4xx_hal::delay::Delay;
use rtt_target::{rtt_init_print, rprintln};
use stm32f4xx_hal::timer::{Counter, Timer, SysCounter, CounterUs};
use cortex_m::peripheral::SYST;
use stm32f4xx_hal::time::Hertz;
use core::fmt::Debug;
use stm32f4xx_hal::pac::TIM2;
use core::pin::Pin;


fn dbg<T: Debug>(d: T, tag: &str) -> T {
    rprintln!("{} {:?}", tag, d);
    d
}


fn waste(c_us: &CounterUs<TIM2>, us: u32) {
    let ts1 = c_us.now().ticks();
    while (c_us.now().ticks() - ts1) < us {}
}

fn waste_until<T>(c_us: &CounterUs<TIM2>,
                  predicate: fn(_: &T) -> bool,
                  dt: &T,
                  us: u32) -> u32 {
    let ts1 = c_us.now().ticks();
    while (c_us.now().ticks() - ts1) < us && !predicate(dt) {}
    return c_us.now().ticks() - ts1;
}

#[entry]
fn main() -> ! {
    if let (Some(dp), Some(cp)) = (
        pac::Peripherals::take(),
        cortex_m::peripheral::Peripherals::take(),
    ) {
        rtt_init_print!();
        let gpioa = dp.GPIOA.split();
        let mut trig = gpioa.pa3.into_push_pull_output();
        let mut echo = gpioa.pa4.into_pull_up_input();
        let rcc = dp.RCC.constrain();
        let clocks = rcc.cfgr.freeze();
        let mut counter = Timer::new(dp.TIM2, &clocks).counter_us();
        counter.start(1_000_000_u32.micros()).unwrap();
        loop {
            trig.set_low();
            waste(&counter, 2);
            trig.set_high();
            waste(&counter, 10);
            trig.set_low();
            let _ = waste_until(&counter, |c|c.is_high(),&echo, 1000);
            let pulse_duration = waste_until(&counter, |c| c.is_low(),&echo, 1000);
            rprintln!("{}", pulse_duration);
        }
    }

    loop {}
}
```

I know that the code at this point does not stop the evaluation of the data in the case of timeout in the `waste_until` function, but given that there is an object less then 10 cm from sensor (which has a range of up to 2 meters) it shouldn't be causing issues.

I have few things I don't understand completely, which I assume might be the cause of this behavior.

1. First of all, I'm not sure if hardware timers loop, or have to be reset manually. (I used my waste function with half a second delay and managed to make seemingly ok blinky program, so i hope i got it correct).
2. I'm not sure if i have to configure my `TIM2` maximum sampling frequency as in theory I could do it with `sysclock`, but i didn't find a way to do it with TIM2. Also I assumed that it wouldn't let me create `CounterUs` without minimum valid sample rate.
3. I'm not sure if `ticks()` are in one to one relation with microseconds (only assumed so, because it seemed logical that `CounterUs` would do that).
4. I'm not sure about the problems which might occur if timer loops mid wait and delta time becomes negative (in case of u32 just overflows).
5. When it comes to `pull_up_input` and `pull_down_input` does `pull_up` refer to the fact that pin is usually pulled high, and to trigger logical one it has to go low or that it has to be pulled high to get logical one? (Also it is not very clear if the `is_low()` and `is_high()` methods refer to the state of the pin, or logical value of the pin?)

I spent quite some time on this thing, but sadly to no avail so far. Hopefully someone can tell me if one of the things above is wrong and indeed causes the issue, or if its not something I considered helped me to see it.
(Value I'm getting is 1000 - 1001)

---

So from one of the comments I found out about the pull down and pull up resistors and watched couple YouTube videos on the matter. Not sure if this is correct, but from what I've found it seems that in fact i need a `pull_down_input` for echo pin. So I replaced it and the value
I'm getting is still constant but it's 1 now.

Now that makes some sense, since I assume that 1000 was originating from the timeout value in my `waste`. But getting 1 is a bit more confusing, I mean it cannot be faster then 1 us, right?

---

So after experimenting some more, I've ended up with this version of the code:

```rust
#![deny(unsafe_code)]
#![allow(clippy::empty_loop)]
#![no_main]
#![no_std]


use panic_halt as _; // panic handler

use cortex_m_rt::{entry, interrupt};
use stm32f4xx_hal as hal;

use crate::hal::{pac, prelude::*};
use stm32f4xx_hal::delay::Delay;
use rtt_target::{rtt_init_print, rprintln};
use stm32f4xx_hal::timer::{Counter, Timer, SysCounter, CounterUs};
use cortex_m::peripheral::SYST;
use stm32f4xx_hal::time::Hertz;
use core::fmt::Debug;
use stm32f4xx_hal::pac::TIM2;
use core::pin::Pin;
use cortex_m::asm::nop;


fn dbg<T: Debug>(d: T, tag: &str) -> T {
    rprintln!("{} {:?}", tag, d);
    d
}


fn waste(c_us: &CounterUs<TIM2>, us: u32) {
    let ts1 = c_us.now().ticks();
    while (c_us.now().ticks() - ts1) < us {}
}

fn waste_until<T>(c_us: &CounterUs<TIM2>,
                  predicate: fn(_: &T) -> bool,
                  dt: &T,
                  us: u32) -> Option<u32> {

    let ts1 = c_us.now().ticks();
    while (c_us.now().ticks() - ts1) < us && !predicate(dt) {

    }

    if predicate(dt) {Some(c_us.now().ticks() - ts1)} else {None}

}

#[entry]
fn main() -> ! {
    if let (Some(dp), Some(cp)) = (
        pac::Peripherals::take(),
        cortex_m::peripheral::Peripherals::take(),
    ) {
        rtt_init_print!();

        let gpioa = dp.GPIOA.split();
        let mut trig = gpioa.pa4.into_push_pull_output();
        let mut echo = gpioa.pa5.into_pull_down_input();
        let rcc = dp.RCC.constrain();
        let clocks = rcc.cfgr.freeze();
        let mut counter = Timer::new(dp.TIM2, &clocks).counter_us();
        counter.start(1_000_000_u32.micros()).unwrap();

        loop {

            // starting pulse
            trig.set_low();
            waste(&counter, 2);
            trig.set_high();
            waste(&counter, 10);
            trig.set_low();
            // ending pulse

            // starting echo read
            if let Some(_) =  waste_until(&counter, |c|c.is_high(),&echo, 1_000_000) { // if didn't timeout
                if let Some(pulse_duration) = waste_until(&counter, |c| c.is_low(),&echo, 1_000_000) { // if didn't timeout
                    rprintln!("{}", pulse_duration);
                } else {
                    rprintln!("no falling edge");
                }
            } else {
                rprintln!("no rising edge");
            }

            // end echo read

           }


    }

    loop {}
}
```

And here it became clear that the pattern in fact was that first 1-3 readings output same value (so far I've seen 1, 21 and 41) and then it keeps timing out in the outer if.

I tried changing io pins because I considered that my poor solder job was to blame, and also inspected the pins with multimeter, they seem to be fine.

I'm not entirely sure but I think that given that sensor has a recommended VCC of 5 volts, and stlink-2 provides 3.3 volts to the board the sensor can preform worse (but once again the target object is at most 5 cm away).

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ryZB.jpg) are the images of my breadboard just in case i missed something.

Comment: The value i get from that rprintln! call is always 1000 or 1001.

Comment: HIGH = 1, LOW = 0. The pull configuration has no effect on the input read. `pull_up_input` and `pull_down_input` with both read HIGH/1 if the input voltage is near VCC, and both read LOW/0 if the input voltage is near 0. `is_low` and `is_high` just tell you whether the input reads as a 0 or a 1, respectively.

Comment: For `into_pull_up_input`, the `pull_up` refers to the internal pull-up resistor, which is enabled.

Comment: @lkolbly So does that imply that to successfully read low when the echo pin is low i have to have pull_down_input?

Comment: @HerbalTea No, it means that if the pin were unconnected then it would read high (for `pull_up`). You'll be able to successfully read both high and low regardless of which you use, as long as the input is driven.

Comment: I have a similar problem with pico. The echo is constant. Always the same number of beats (whatever beat mechanism I use). I must be missing something obvious.

Comment: Ok, I found my problem. I was using a SR04 which requires 5V and gave it the 3V input. I gave the 5V input, and made sure to have the voltage divider and I was all set. See link here for the voltage divider: https://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/hc-sr04-ultrasonic-range-sensor-on-the-raspberry-pi